# Time Series estimation on specific lags on MA part

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I need to estimate specific lag ARMA model. Here is an example.

```
ts1 <- arima.sim(list(order = c(0, 0, 5), ma = c(0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0.1)), n = 1000)
```

The above model is $X_t = Z_t + 0.7 Z_{t-2} +0.1 Z_{t-5}$, where $\{ Z_t\}$ is white noise.

Is it possible to estimate this model in R? I tried `arima` function and I haven't found the option to specify the specific lag.

If it is not possible in R, is there any specific reason?

Comment: Perhaps you need commercial software that allows more general specifications that might also include the identification and incorporation of Pulses/Level Shifts/Local Time Trends or the optimal power trasnformation. Three products come to mind SAS ,SPSS and AUTOBOX (which I am involved with ) .If you want to post your data I will post the results.

Comment: Thanks IrishStat. I am looking the specific details in R.

Comment: Is this what you're looking to do? `code`arima(x=ts1, order=c(0,0,5), fixed=c(0,NA,0,0,NA,0))`code`

Comment: Thanks Graeme. I think this will do the job. How `fixed` will be different when AR part and constant also involved in the model?

Comment: @Kalman In `fixed` the order will be AR coefficients then MA coefficients then the last one is the constant. Here is an example from which you should be able to decipher how it works: `ts2 <- arima.sim(list(order = c(2, 0, 3), ar=c(0.3, 0.4), ma = c( 0, 0, 0.2)), n = 1000)` `arima(x=ts2, order=c(2,0,3), fixed=c(NA,NA,0,0,NA,0))` It should be easy enough to figure out, but let us know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks Graeme.  This solves my question. Please update your solution, so that I can make this question as solved.

Comment: @Kalman No problem Kalman. I've updated my solution. Glad to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem to be solved here is to estimate an ARIMA model in R and set some of the coefficients in the model to be constrained to be equal to zero.

Specifically, the task is to estimate an ARIMA(0,0,5) model, or equivalently an MA(5) model, and set the moving average terms at lags 1, 3, and 4, equal to zero. In addition, the constant term is also to be constrained to equal zero.

To do this, we use the `arima()` function and make use of the `fixed` argument. The fixed argument allows us to set these constraints. The `arima()` help page (by typing `?arima` in R) tells us about the `fixed` argument:

> `fixed` optional numeric vector of the same length as the total number
>   of parameters. If supplied, only NA entries in fixed will be varied.

In R, we can estimate the aforementioned model with constraints by running the code shown below:

```
# Estimate MA(5) model with constraints using fixed=c()
arima(x=ts1, order=c(0,0,5), fixed=c(0,NA,0,0,NA,0))
```

Let's take a closer look at `fixed=c(0,NA,0,0,NA,0)`.

- The first 0 in the vector constrains the MA term at lag 1 to equal to zero.
- The next element in the vector, NA, refers to the MA term at lag 2 and by specifying NA (as opposed to 0) we impose no constraint.
- The next two 0's in the vector constrain the MA terms at lags 3 and 4 to equal zero.
- The second NA refers to the MA term at lag 5 and sets no constraint.
- The last element in the vector is a 0 and this has the function of setting the constant term equal to zero.

In general, the elements in the `fixed` vector will refer to AR terms then MA terms and finally the constant - in that sequence. Again, note that the length of the `fixed` vector should equal the length of the total number of parameters to be estimated. For example, in an MA(5) model (as above), there are 6 parameters to be estimated (5 MA terms and 1 constant) and that's the reason why there are 6 elements in the `fixed` vector.